# 405 not allowed - php mail

Tags: php, html

Im getting this html message "405 not allowed nginx" when im trying to post to the same page.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="contact-form-col">
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $msg = 'Name: ' .$_POST['name'] ."\n"
            .'Email: ' .$_POST['email'] ."\n"
            .'Phone: ' .$_POST['phone'] ."\n"
            .'Message: ' .$_POST['message'];
        mail('EMAIL NAME' , 'Contact form message', $msg);
        echo "Message was send";
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong.";
    }
?>
```

My question is, what im doing wrong and how can I keep the message inside the form div without redirecting to the contact.php page for example?

Also is htmlentities necessary in this case? when im not echo anything besides "Email was send"?

Answer (score 0):

if your submitting the form from the html page you need to have a php script to process the request.

But if the html code is in a php page  your code is fine but there is a small error

the solution is

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $msg = 'Name: ' .$_POST['name'] ."\n"
        .'Email: ' .$_POST['email'] ."\n"
        .'Phone: ' .$_POST['phone'] ."\n"
        .'Message: ' .$_POST['message'];

 $go =   mail($to, $subject,  $msg, $headers);


   if(!$go) {   
       echo "Something went wrong.";// error
      } else {
        echo "Message was send";// correct

         }

} 
?>
```

I hope this will work for you.